# I can't find what is wrong with this react code but when try to console.log the item, i get undefined for everything expect note field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, function, class

I can't find what is wrong with this react code but when try to console.log the item, i get undefined for all the fields except note field. I decided to use class based component hoping it was function component that was causing the error but class component stated saying typeError firstName is null.

This is the function component and the error message

```
Object
address: undefined
birthday: undefined
company: undefined
email: undefined
firstName: undefined
lastName: undefined
note: "d"
phone: undefined
socialProfile: undefined
url: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function Phonebookform() {

  const [phonebook, setPhonebook] = useState({
    firstName:'',
    lastName:'',
    company:'',
    phone:'',
    email:'',
    note:'',
    url:'',
    address:'',
    birthday:'',
    socialProfile:''

  })

  const handleChange = (e) =>{
    setPhonebook({
      [e.target.name]:e.target.value
    })
    
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const item = {
      firstName: phonebook.firstName,
      lastName: phonebook.lastName,
      company: phonebook.company,
      phone: phonebook.phone,
      email: phonebook.email,
      url: phonebook.url,
      note: phonebook.note,
      address: phonebook.address,
      birthday: phonebook.birthday,
      socialProfile: phonebook.socialProfile
      
    }
    console.log(item)
    
  }
  
  return (
    
    <form id='form' onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
     
      <input name='firstName' value={phonebook.firstName} onChange={handleChange} type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
    
       
      <input name='lastName' value={phonebook.lastName} onChange={handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
      
    
      <input name='company' value={phonebook.company} onChange={handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Company" />
     
      <input name='phone' value={phonebook.phone} onChange={handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Phone" />
      
    
        <input name='email' type="email" value={phonebook.email} placeholder=" email" />
      
      
      <input name='date' value={phonebook.date} onChange={handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Date" />
      
     
      <input value={phonebook.url} onChange={handleChange} name='url' type="text" placeholder="URL" />
      
      
      <input name='birthday' value={phonebook.birthday} onChange={handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Birthday" />
      
    
      <input  name='socialProfile' value={phonebook.socialProfile} onChange={handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Social Profile" />
      
     
      <input  name='note' value={phonebook.note} onChange={handleChange}  rows={3} placeholder='Note'/>
      
      
        <button  id='form_btn' type="submit">
        Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    )

  
}

export default Phonebookform
```

this is the class component and the error message

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of null`

```
class Phonebookform extends Component {

State = {
    firstName:'',
    lastName:'',
    company:'',
    phone:'',
    email:'',
    note:'',
    url:'',
    address:'',
    birthday:'',
    socialProfile:''
  }

   handleChange = (e) =>{
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]:e.target.value
    })
    
  }

   handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const item = {
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName,
      company: this.state.company,
      phone: this.state.phone,
      email: this.state.email,
      url: this.state.url,
      note: this.state.note,
      address: this.state.address,
      birthday: this.state.birthday,
      socialProfile: this.state.socialProfile
      
    }
    console.log(item)
    
  }
 render(){
  return (
    
    <Form id='form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
      <Form.Row>
    <Form.Group as={Col} >
      <Form.Label>First Name</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control name='firstName' value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group as={Col} >
      <Form.Label>Last Name</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control name='lastName' value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
    </Form.Group>
    </Form.Row>
    <Form.Row>
    <Form.Group as={Col} >
      <Form.Label>Company</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control name='company' value={this.state.company} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Company" />
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group as={Col} >
      <Form.Label>Phone</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control name='phone' value={this.state.phone} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Phone" />
    </Form.Group>
    </Form.Row>
    <Form.Row>
    <Form.Group as={Col} >
      <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control name='email' type="email" value={this.state.email} placeholder=" email" />
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group as={Col} >
      <Form.Label>Date</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control name='date' value={this.state.date} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Date" />
    </Form.Group>
    </Form.Row>
    <Form.Row>
    <Form.Group as={Col} >
      <Form.Label>URL</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control value={this.state.url} onChange={this.handleChange} name='url' type="text" placeholder="URL" />
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group as={Col} >
      <Form.Label>Birthday</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control  name='birthday' value={this.state.birthday} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Birthday" />
    </Form.Group>
    
    <Form.Group as={Col} >
      <Form.Label>Social </Form.Label>
      <Form.Control  name='socialProfile' value={this.state.socialProfile} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Social Profile" />
    </Form.Group>
    </Form.Row>
    <Form.Group >
      <Form.Label>Note</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control as="textarea" name='note' value={this.state.note} onChange={this.handleChange}  rows={3} placeholder='Note'/>
    </Form.Group>
    
    
    <Button  id='form_btn' variant="primary"  type="submit">
      Submit
    </Button>
  </Form>
    )
 } 
 
}

export default Phonebookform
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stick with the functional component. The issue is that you are changing the phonebook object to only contain one property.

I think you want something like this:

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setPhonebook((prevPhonebook) => ({
      ...prevPhonebook,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  };
```

I'm not sure if you've seen the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) before, but this will allow you to maintain the previous values and also update the changed value.

Example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-galois-1xvq2?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Can i get some help with aa code please that my letters turn red and when i try to rebuild project it says. cannot find symbol
Items item = new Items(    )

Comment: This answer doesn't appear related to the original poster's question. If you have a new issue, I suggest posting a new question after reviewing these helpful guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Good luck!